# Using jQuery to choose correct button in table

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I Have an HTML table with a button in each row. How can I write a jQuery function which will pick the value of a column in that row where the button is clicked. 
table is created as expected. but i want that button click function.....
there is a div named tablecontent.
thanks in advanced

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Test.aspx/HTMLCONTROLRECVDATA",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "Json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#tablecontent").html(result.d);`//add table html is attach with div`}
        });
</script>
```

C# code:

```
public static string HTMLCONTROLRECVDATA()
{
     string connetionString = "Data Source=ARNAB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ABC;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_mom_HTMLCONTROLRECVDATA", cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cnn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(rdr);
    DataRowCollection drows = dt.Rows;
    StringBuilder HTML = new StringBuilder();
    HTML.AppendLine("<table border='1' id='mainTable'>");
    foreach (DataRow dr in drows)
    {
        HTML.AppendLine("<tr>");
        HTML.AppendFormat("<td>" + dr["AssociateID"] + "</td>\n<td>" + dr["AssociateName"] + "</td><td> <input type='button' class='Button2' value='submit' style='height:20px;width:80px' /></td>\n");
        HTML.AppendLine("</tr>");

    }
    HTML.AppendLine("</table>");
    cnn.Close();
    return HTML.ToString();
}
```

Comment: And when does c# come into play?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

**Edit:** For better understanding `.parent()` takes the parent `<tr>` and `.next('tr td')` takes the next data-cell

```js
$('button[name=btntbl]').click(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().next('tr td').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablebtns">
<tr><th><button name="btntbl">Button Row 1</button></th><td>Test1</td></tr>
<tr><th><button name="btntbl">Button Row 2</button></th><td>Test2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: it works but when the table created by c# code than it does not work.